# English Translation of Rabbi Y. Salanter's Igeret ha-Musar?

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, jewish-books, translation, mussar-ethics

Where can I find a decent-quality (but preferably good) and free English translation of Igeret Hamusar on the Internet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you wanted? http://www.aishdas.org/igeresHamussar.pdf